# i failed to connect with database in eclipse

Tags: java, oracle, tns

when i tried to connect Oracle Database with Eclipse at first
i got Error in this part -> 'Data Source Explorer/Database Connection ->new Oracle'
but , i resolved it

1. by changing 'service name - db' into 'checking SID and writing orcl' in properties ->general part

(at the first time when i connected to Oracle Database, ORA 12505 happend, but i used other SID that i
can use [cmd -lsnrctl services-> i found DEDICATED, READY SID] so that probloem was resolved.)

2. by changing 'Host - server' into 'Host - localhost'

i thought it would work certainly. and runned tomcat server.
but it still doesn't work

when i checked console, i could find this error message.

============================================================================

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:

    ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

     )

        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:668)

        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:543)

        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:752)

        at sec02.ex02.MemberDAO.listMembers(MemberDAO.java:33)

        at sec02.ex02.MemberServlet.doHandle(MemberServlet.java:49)

        at sec02.ex02.MemberServlet.doGet(MemberServlet.java:20)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
```

## (...)

how can i resolve it.......

Comment: can you provide your connection details for the eclipse pool ? I guess you are using a wrong TNS string